# The Mystery: I've mined some BTCs with Bitcoin Core 0.9.0, however the system no longer synchronizes and in the blockchain the balance is zero

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, malware

I got some BTCs using a Bitcoin Core 9 version beta, from August to December 2019, they are listed in my history as "generated" and with several confirmations with one, the balance appears in my system, however when I put the key or the hash on a blockchain explorer there is no balance.
Another problem is that my system is stuck, it doesn't synchronize anymore, I've tried using a 0.20 and 0.18 Bitcoin Core, I copied the wallet to the new systems but then the transactions appear without validation, even synchronizing the system.

Does anyone know what I should do?

Below some screenshots

[image: Bitcoin core version]

[image: BTC mined]

[image: Transations]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110924/discussion-on-question-by-dg-br-the-mystery-ive-btcs-mined-from-bitcore-9-0-mi).

Answer (score 2):

As outlined in the comments, there's a couple of possibilities here:

1. You downloaded a very old version of Bitcoin Core, and managed to end up on a private chain where CPU mining is possible, and the chain is still new enough that the block reward is 50 BTC
2. The program you downloaded is a Bitcoin clone and gives the illusion of paying out 50 BTC or more, while either stealing crypto keys from other wallets on your computer, or later on asking you to pay some kind of recovery or unlock fee to claim these mined coins.

In either case, there is no Bitcoin. The block reward has not been 50 BTC for many, many years now (it was 12.5 BTC in 2019, and is currently 6.25 BTC in July 2020). Regardless of what method you used to mine, it is simply impossible to have a 50 BTC block reward dated in 2019 on the Bitcoin mainnet.

In short, you're either being scammed, or are mining on a private Bitcoin network with no relation to the public mainnet.

As Murch said in the comments below, you should definitely NOT use any address generated by this software to receive Bitcoin from an external wallet, exchange, or other service. All of these will send you real, mainnet Bitcoin.

As your version of Bitcoin Core is, at best, on a private network, you will not be able to access any externally received coins until you move your keys into a legitimate wallet that connects to the public Bitcoin network.

At worst, you're running some form of malware, and any real coins sent to addresses generated by this software will be stolen by whoever wrote it.

Comment: You may want to add that this software should under no circumstances be used to receive actual bitcoin payments.

Comment: @Murch Fair point, editing it in

Comment: Good evening everyone. I understood perfectly the answers and doubts about the veracity of the operation, but I also found some articles talking about people who had BTCs in the same situation, so, aside from the criticisms and supposed arguments that it would be a fraud or maleware, someone in this group would have any idea , even if improbable, how could we move this over the network and get these credits for exchange?

Comment: You can't. Those coins don't exist. There is nothing you can do to make them exist.